# ForEach-Object -Parallel Parameter set cannot be resolved

Tags: powershell

When using powershell and following [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) running the following example throws an error.

Example:
`1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { "Hello $_"; sleep 1; } -ThrottleLimit 5`

Error:
`ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

Removing the body of the loop does not resolve the issue. It is present whenever using the -Parallel keyword.

The article is from last year which makes me think the feature must still be present in powershell. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Get-Help ForEach-Object ..

Comment: Those options (parallel and throttlelimit) are only available in PS 7. W10 fully updated is on 5.1 still. Look at the first line of the article you linked.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue when trying to test the script in the Windows Powershell ISE script editor, despite `pwsh --version` telling me that it was `7.2.0`.

As [Owain Esau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7287932/owain-esau) points out in the comments, the error is telling you that the current version of `ForEach-Object` does not support the `-Parallel` parameter.

But if you open run your script in a dedicated Powershell 7 window, it should execute just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kylaaa mentioned, this is a powershell version issue. Be sure you are running `pwsh` instead of `powershell`. I just learned of this distinction and although I was running command in Powershell 7.2.2 window, `powershell` command was running a different interpreter resulting in the error.